# Exterior powers and restriction of scalars

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $ R $ and $ S $ be two commutative rings and let $ f\colon R\to S $ be a homomorphism of rings. For any $ S $-module $ N $ denote with $ f^*N $ the module obtained from $ N $ by restriction of scalars ($ r\cdot_R n = f(r)n $).

Now, given $ N $ one can obtain an $ R $-module in the two following ways: first take the exterior power of $ N $ and then immediately restrict the scalars, $ f^*\bigwedge_S^k N $; or first restrict the scalars and then take the exterior power, $ \bigwedge_R^k f^*N $.

Is there any relationship between $ f^*\bigwedge_S^k N $ and $ \bigwedge_R^k f^*N $? Are they isomorphic?

Comment: Consider $\Bbb R\hookrightarrow\Bbb C$ for instance. I expect there's a natural transformation $\bigwedge_R^kf^\ast\to f^\ast\bigwedge^k_S$.

Comment: Have you looked at a single example before asking?

Comment: I tired to show that $ f^*\bigwedge_S^k N $ verify the same universal property of $ \bigwedge_R f^* N $, but I didn't succeed. I'm not sure I understand $ \bigwedge^k\mathbb C $ really well and I didn't want to spend an evening on the issue, so I thought that asking for help was the safest thing to do.

Comment: @GeometriaDifferenziale How did you fail at verifying the universal property? This is what you should put in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as suggested by @coiso and @Martin Brandenburg I'll look at a concrete example: $ \iota\colon \mathbb R\hookrightarrow \mathbb C $. Then
$$
\dim_{\mathbb R}\iota^*\mathbb C^n = 2n\quad \leadsto\quad \dim_{\mathbb R}\bigwedge\nolimits_{\mathbb R}^k \iota^*\mathbb C^n = \binom{2n}{k}
$$
but
$$
\dim_{\mathbb C}C^n = n\text{,}\, \dim_{\mathbb C}\bigwedge\nolimits_{\mathbb C}^k\mathbb C^n = \binom{n}{k}\quad\leadsto \quad \dim_{\mathbb R}\iota^*\bigwedge\nolimits_{\mathbb C}^k\mathbb C^n = 2\binom{n}{k}
$$
and in general they are different.

I still have to work out the natural transformation
$$
\bigwedge\nolimits_R^kf^\ast\to f^\ast\bigwedge\nolimits^k_S
$$
but I hope I could do it. Sorry for the rush!